# GHCi doesn't work with FFI export declarations/shared libraries

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghci

I have a problem regarding FFI in Haskell and the interactive mode of GHC.

(Source is also available via a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2366554)):

FFISo.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

foreign import ccall "callMeFromHaskell"
  callMeFromHaskell :: IO ()

foreign export ccall callMeFromC :: IO ()
callMeFromC :: IO ()
callMeFromC = B.putStrLn "callMeFromC"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  B.putStrLn "main"
  callMeFromHaskell
  return ()
```

c.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void callMeFromC(void);

void callMeFromHaskell(void)
{   
    printf("callMeFromHaskell\n");
    callMeFromC();
}
```

Makefile:

```
GHC_OPT := -Wall -O2 -fno-warn-unused-do-bind

all: ffiso

test: ffiso
    ./$<

ffiso: FFISo.hs c.c
    ghc --make $(GHC_OPT) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.hi *.o ffiso *_stub.*

ghci0: ffiso
    echo main | ghci FFISo.hs

ghci1: ffiso
    echo main | ghci FFISo.hs c.o

ghci2: ffiso
    echo main | ghci FFISo.hs c.o FFISo.o
```

Compiling and linking works fine:

```
$ make test
ghc --make -Wall -O2 -fno-warn-unused-do-bind FFISo.hs c.c -o ffiso
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( FFISo.hs, FFISo.o )
Linking ffiso ...
./ffiso
main
callMeFromHaskell
callMeFromC
```

However, if I want to use GHCi, it fails with this message:

```
$ make ghci0
echo main | ghci FFISo.hs
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude Main> Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
<interactive>: FFISo.o: unknown symbol `callMeFromHaskell'

Prelude Main> Leaving GHCi.
```

Well, let's try giving GHCi the `c.o` objectfile.

```
$ make ghci1
echo main | ghci FFISo.hs c.o
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading object (static) c.o ... done
ghc: c.o: unknown symbol `callMeFromC'
linking extra libraries/objects failed
make: *** [ghci1] Error 1
final link ...
```

Oh okay... let's try with FFISo.o:

```
$ make ghci2
echo main | ghci FFISo.hs c.o FFISo.o
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading object (static) c.o ... done
Loading object (static) FFISo.o ... done
ghc: FFISo.o: unknown symbol `bytestringzm0zi9zi2zi1_DataziByteStringziInternal_PS_con_info'
linking extra libraries/objects failed
make: *** [ghci2] Error 1
final link ...
```

And that's where I'm stuck.

I tested it with two different environments with the same result:

```
$ # system 1
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
$ uname -a
Linux phenom 3.2.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 24 09:10:39 CET 2012 x86_64 AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux

$ # system 2
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
$ uname -a
Linux hermann 2.6.32-22-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 3 23:14:23 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify some more objects to link when invoking GHCi, because the C object `c.o` is particularly picky when it comes to linking order.

First, you need to add the `bytestring` package's object files. This is done by adding `-package bytestring` to the GHCi command line.

Then, you need to add the actual object file that defines `callMeFromC`. When `FFISo.hs` is compiled, it doesn't produce an object file that exports `callMeFromC`. It instead uses the GHC naming convention and exports `Main_zdfcallMeFromCzuak4_closure`, which actually is a static global variable pointing to the closure/"thunk" that contains the actual function definition and environment. This is so that you can't write something like this:

```
foregin export ccall foo :: IO ()
foo = undefined
```

...and have the runtime crash as soon as the program starts because the "function value" of `foo` can't be evaluated. The function definition is only inspected once the function is actually used.

GHC generates a stub file, which contains C code for calling the Haskell function from C. This file is called `FFISo_stub.c`, and is compiled into `FFISo_stub.o` for you. This object file exports the "C version" of `callMeFromC` that can be called directly. Feel free to inspect the generated code, it is quite interesting.

All in all, you need to use this command line when invoking GHCi:

```
ghci -package bytestring FFISo.o c.o FFISo_stub.o FFISo.hs
```