# Make GHCi load and interpret a module with a "foreign export" declaration (for FFI with C)?

Tags: haskell, ghci, ffi

I have a module (`Safe.hs`) with

```
foreign export ccall respond_hs :: CWString -> IO CWString
```

for FFI with C.

I'd like to load `Safe.hs` in GHCi and evaluate some things with it.

But `ghci` fails to load it (I'm specifying two source files because it depends on `valencies.lhs`):

```
$ ghci src/valencies.lhs src/Safe.hs 
GHCi, version 7.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 2] Compiling Valencies        ( src/valencies.lhs, interpreted ) [flags changed]

[2 of 2] Compiling Safe             ( src/Safe.hs, interpreted )

src/Safe.hs:10:1:
    Illegal foreign declaration: requires via-C, llvm (-fllvm) or native code generation (-fvia-C)
    When checking declaration:
      foreign export ccall "respond_hs" respond_hs
        :: CWString -> IO CWString
Failed, modules loaded: Valencies.
*Valencies> :q
Leaving GHCi.
$
```

Giving `-fvia-C` option doesn't help.

#### Related questions

- This is a different question from [Testing FFI Code with GHCi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15677323/94687), where the point was in testing Haskell code with `foreign import` (not `export`) from C libraries.
- [GHCi doesn't work with FFI export declarations/shared libaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123040/94687) seems strange to me, because it doesn't help me. It deals with `foreign export` from Haskell to C, but the problem solved there is some missing object files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, as [told by Dirk Thierbach](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.haskell/wloDdit9gO4), there are two helpful options in this case:

> If you look up -fvia-C in the GHC manual, section flag reference,
>   you're redirected to section 4.10.6 (Options affecting code
>   generation). There you'll find, near -fvia-C:
>
> > `-fobject-code`
> >
> > Generate object code. This is the default outside of GHCi, and can
> >     be used with GHCi to cause object code to be generated in preference
> >     to bytecode.
> >
> > `-fbyte-code`
> >
> > Generate byte-code instead of object-code. This is the default in
> >     GHCi. Byte-code can currently only be used in the interactive
> >     interpreter, not saved to disk. This option is only useful for
> >     reversing the effect of `-fobject-code`.
>
> That explains why it works with GHC, but not with GHCI.

So, I happily do `ghci -fobject-code src/valencies.lhs src/Safe.hs` now.

#### Related questions

- [GHCi doesn't work with FFI export declarations/shared libaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123040/94687) first seemed a mess to me, because it didn't help me. It deals with `foreign export` from Haskell to C, too, but the problem solved there is some missing object files, which you must give to GHCi for it to link everything. In my case, I simply omit linking with the C part of the program, because I don't need it to test the Haskell module. After re-reading that Q&A, I can suspect that giving an `.o` to GHCi can simply silently switch GHCi to the correct mode!

If all you want is to test the Haskell module, and if its functions can work in isolation from C functions (i.e., they don't call C functions), I believe the option I have discovered is a simpler way than to add more `.o` files to the command line to make GHCi link everything (you see, there might be further requirements to link with some C functions from other packages, which is not important for you).